# Celular vibrando no modo silencioso mesmo com a propriedade vibrate : null usando o plugin local notification no ionic

Tags: ionic, cordova-plugin, local-notification

Quero que meu aplicativo mostre uma barra de progresso quando eu iniciar um download ou upload. Para isso estou usando os plugins fileTransfer, local notifications. O valor do progresso é dado de acordo com a mudança de uma variável que recebe o valor de um observável. ao atualizar a notificação Usei o método update, mas a cada atualização ele vibra novamente.
NOTA: Quando o celular tem volume, ele não vibra, resultado que quero alcançar no silencioso.
Pagnas visitadas:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/local-notifications
https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications

```
this.apiService.getContObservable().subscribe(res => {
  console.log('Novo Valor: ', res)
  if (res == 1) {
    this.cont = res / 100
    this.aux = res
    this.criarNoficacao()

  } else if (res == 100) {
    this.cont = 0
    this.aux = 0
  } else {
    this.cont = res / 100
    this.aux = res
    this.notificacao.update({
      id: 1,
      sound: null,
      vibrate : null,
      progressBar: { value: this.aux }
    });
  
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Descobri que no localNotification existe uma propriedade chamada silent, que quando definida como verdadeiro não permite que o celular nem toque nem vibre